# Not cycling through img .src changes on 'click'

Tags: javascript

I have set up a piece of javascript that is meant to operate as a slideshow where you have to click right or left to go each way through an array of images. As it is, it only has 3 images and one button (the blue div) for going one way through the array.

I have scoured this code over and over and tried to separate the pieces of it but I could discern no pattern over what works. I have been stuck at this stage for months, and would therefore really appreciate some help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#clicker { width: 200px; height:200px; background: blue; }
#pic { width: 300px; height: 150px; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="clicker"></div>
<img id="pic" src="models_web.jpg" alt="Icon" />


<script type="text/javascript">

var imgs = ["models_web.jpg","reflex_2.jpg","blue_web.jpg"];
var i = 0;
var addl = document.getELementById("clicker");

function clickrotate() {

document.getElementById("pic").src = imgs[i];
i++
if (i === 2) {i = 0};

}
addl.addEventListener( "click", clickrotate, false ) ;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you need help with? What's your question?

Comment: also theres a possibility that its just i++ without a ; thats preventing it from loading if thats your problem and not just a question error

Comment: `if (i === 2) {i = 0};` you should check here if `i===3` if you want to go that way, as with your condition, it will never load third image

Comment: I chose i===2 because it should go 0-1-2, so 2 represents the third part of the array?

Comment: I  have added a semicolon to the increment, that didn't fix it. As for the increment thing, I have put the i++, then the .src change, then the 'if else' statement and that seems to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your script.

`var addl = document.getELementById("clicker");`

change to `var addl = document.getElementById("clicker");`

Another thing, your counter increment is wrong. It will reset after viewing the second image, because you check `i === 2` *after* incrementing it.

If you check the console in the developer tools in any modern browser, you will see what's wrong. It will save you the headaches next time.

Comment: I cannot see any typo there?

Comment: @lazyrabbit Capital L is a typo.

Comment: Fair enough! ty for your input I know it's a lame question.